# How to trigger built in iOS OCR Scanner | Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

Looking for a way to auto trigger the keyboard OCR scanner to get called and open using Swift, can this be done? I cannot seem to find any references online for how this can be triggered. If there is a way to trigger this in SwiftUI that would be better.

For reference, this is what I would like to trigger with a button tap or function:

[image]